# Vagrant - Global Setup among many sites + domain aliases

Tags: vagrant

Coming from a MAMP Pro background, I loved the ability to have a "base" folder (`/Sites` in this case), have all of my projects underneath it and set custom server names/aliases with it. With Vagrant, it looks like I can accomplish the name/alias part with [vagrant-hostsupdater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater), but if I really did just want to have the Vagrant files in `/Sites` and then all of them use the same config, what's the best way to specify a subfolder disk location with those custom host names?

I'm most likely over-thinking this, have just been a sucker for GUI interfaces and would love to know how to accomplish this. Thanks as always!

## Clarification

#### What I'm used to

I used to use MAMP Pro, which allows you to setup custom host additions with their GUI interface. So, within my `~/Sites` directory, I have several different projects going on, all in subfolders. The screen shot below shows how I can set a server name and specify a disk location, all from this central location.

[image: MAMP Pro]

#### What I'd like to do with Vagrant

Now I do know of (and used [vagrant-hostsupdater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater)), but what I was wondering is if I can set my Vagrant file in my `~/Sites` directory (which is kind of like the root of the server; since all of my projects require the same setup) and then have individual host names setup for each project - so instead of having to access a subfolder like `local.dev/project-1` or `local.dev/project-2 I could setup server names such as`local.project-1.com`and`local.project-2.com` from within that top-level Vagrant file and specify the subfolder it should attach that rewrite rule too.

The reason I'd like to do this is so I only have to run one `vagrant up` and I can then access all of my projects from one Vagrant instance as well as only keep track of one Vagrant file.  Thanks!

Comment: A `Vagrantfile` is interpreted ruby and you can pretty much do what you like.  Asking for the `best way` is rather objective and can't really be answered.  Can you give more details as to what it is you are looking to achieve?

Comment: Hey Steve - agreed and thanks for the tip. I've updated my original question with a bit more clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Vagrant uses different boxes. You need a provisoner to do this and you need to code. Use puppet or chef for start. If you need further guidance on how to setup it then open it as a different question. Tip search for puppet provisioning.

Comment: So with the one `vagrant up` are you looking for a multi node up, or are you looking more for one box acting as a webserver for everything?

Comment: I'm looking for one box for everything under the ~/Sites directory

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `vagrant` what hostnames you would like to use.

### Directory based hostnames

Assuming you set you would like to set your hostnames based on the directory name; you can get all of the hostnames with ruby and pass them to the hostsupdater configuration.

```
SITES_DIR = "~/Sites"
config.hostsupdater.aliases = Dir["#{SITES_DIR}/*/"].map { |d| d.chomp('/') }
```

### Configuration based hostnames

Alternatively you can mock up some sort of configuration that is desirable to you and what you are trying to do and evaluate/process it in ruby within the `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: Thanks for this - I guess the other part would be also modifying the Apache sites-available/000-default.conf file, right? Is there a way to also pass in those same sites to a bash script that would write to that? Thanks again.

Comment: Modifying the default vhost would be beneficial if all of the domains used the same directory.  You would want to generate a specific vhost for each directory/hostname you set up.  This isn't too difficult of a task once you figure out your approach on provisioning.  I use chef, http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html explains the different providers.

Comment: Ideally you would have a generic common vhost in an `erb` template to have ruby fill in the variables for each host.  It's a little more difficult to achieve that with a shell provisioner, so I'd recommend using one of the provisioners with template support.  Unless you're working on something server specific, you can probably find a `cookbook`, `manifest`, or `playbook` that already does what you need to do.

Comment: I do appreciate the information on that so I upvoted your answer. I haven't had any luck as of yet. I know that Vagrant is typically setup per project, but what I'm honestly trying to do is knock out the need for MAMP, Ruby, NodeJS, etc on my local machine and have it all contained within this one directory. Are there any GUI interfaces for creating these cookbook's online? If so, I'm just thinking my "specific" case of having a more global Vagrant install might put me at another roadblock.

Comment: If you go the chef route `knife` would be the standard command line tool for creating cookbooks.  You can find a good bit of community cookbooks at http://community.opscode.com

Comment: I suppose the major issue here is that Vagrant doesn't have to be done any specific way. It's configuration is written in ruby which gives limitless possibilities. If you are looking for an all or nothing up/down state a single box will do opposed to a box per domain. The one certain thing is that you will need to write something to provision apache. That can be done many ways as well whether you generate a vhost per site, or go with a `VirtualDocumentRoot` approach.